# my seagate barracuda is showing different model numbers in disk manager

Tags: hard-drive, storage, disk-management

this is the imgur link of my pictures

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmRAa.jpg

for some reason my seagate barracuda 4tb hardrive (ST4000DM004) is showing as a Microsoft storage space device with only 3.8 mgbs. i have tried formating it and trying to change size but it wont let me. even in bios is shows as the seagate model number but in the disk management it shows in a differant model number

Comment: Can you edit in some more details such as if this is a new drive, and if so where you go it from? My immediate feeling is that it's a bootleg drive.

Comment: Looks like the drive might be recognized as part of a storage space. I’m not sure on this. But have a read here: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/83777-remove-drive-storage-pool-storage-spaces-windows-10-a.html - if that storage space shows up, delete it and remove the drive from the storage space. It could be metadata left over on the drive that makes Windows treat it like this.

Answer (score 0):

@appleoddity is right, was set as a metadata left over. went into setting and changed the partition.

Found the answer at this address, it is also in his answer

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/83777-remove-drive-storage-pool-storage-spaces-windows-10-a.html